# How to pass parameters between xsl templates

Tags: xslt, parameters

I have the following xsl file, that joins two xml files by the element "id":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="trans" match="Transaction" use="id" />

<!-- Identity template to copy everything we don't specifically override -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- override for Mail elements -->
<xsl:template match="Mail">
<xsl:copy>
<!-- copy all children as normal -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
<xsl:variable name="myId" select="id" />
  <Transaction_data>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('transactions.xml')">
      <!-- process all transactions with the right ID -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans', $myId)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Transaction_data>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- omit the id element when copying a Transaction -->
<xsl:template match="Transaction/id" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want id to be a parameter. I will obtain the parameter from an xml file:

```
<xsl:param name="usenode" select="*[name() = document('params.xml')/*/join_node]"/>
<xsl:key name="trans" match="Transaction" use="*[name() = document('params.xml')/*/join_node]" />
```

I can print the value of that variable right after these lines, but further, when I want to use that, it seems the value of the variable vanishes. What to do to make the variable visible for the entire file?

EDIT:

OK, I'm trying to ask the question more specificly.

So my goal is that I want the "id" in use attribute of the

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="usenode" select="*[name() = document('params.xml')/*/join_node]"/>
<xsl:key name="trans" match="Transaction" use="*[name() = document('params.xml')/*/join_node]" />

<!-- Identity template to copy everything we don't specifically override -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- override for Mail elements -->
<xsl:template match="Mail">
<xsl:copy>
<!-- copy all children as normal -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
<xsl:variable name="myId" select="$usenode" />
<Transaction_data>
<xsl:for-each select="document('transactions.xml')">
  <!-- process all transactions with the right ID -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans', $myId)" />
</xsl:for-each>
</Transaction_data>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- omit the id element when copying a Transaction -->
<xsl:template match="Transaction/id" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I referring to $usenode, it is not visible. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to do. Do you want the ID to be a parameter which is passed to the XSLT transformation?
Or do you want the ID to be a variable within the XSLT?

Comment: I'd like it to be a parameter read from another xml file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said where you put the xsl:param. If it's a child of xsl:stylesheet, then it's visible throughout the stylesheet. If it's a child of xsl:template, then it's visible only within that template. The title of your post (passing parameters between templates) suggests you want a template parameter (ie. xsl:param as child of xsl:template) - but frankly, you haven't made it at all clear what you are trying to achieve, what you attempted, or how it failed. So I'm downvoting the question.